# Any C++/C equivalent function with sparse in MATLAB

Tags: c++, c, matlab, sparse-matrix, equivalent

I tried to port `m` code to `c` or `cpp`.

In my code there is a line

```
A = sparse(I,J,IA,nR,nC);
```

which converts row index `I`, col index `J`, and data `IA` to sparse matrix `A` with size `nR x nC`.

Is there any equivalent code with C++ or C?

An naïve algorithm to duplicate result in full matrix is

```
double *A;
A = malloc(sizeof(double)*nR*nC);
memset(A, 0, sizeof(double));

for(k=0; k<size_of_IA; k++)
    A[I[k]*nC + J[k]] += IA[k];
```

Note that if there is common indices, the value is not over overwritten, but accumulated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eigen is an example of a C++ math matrix library that cobtains sparse matrices.  It overloads operators to make it feel like a built in feature.

There are many C and C++ matrix libraries.  None ship as part of `std`, nor is there anything built in.

Writing a good sparse matrix library would be quite hard; your best bet is finding a pre-written one.  Recommendation questions are off topic

Comment: Thanks. I knew that there is eigen which supports sparse matrix manipulation, but I didn't know that there is equivalent function. I read the documentation and I found that `setFromTriplets` is what I wanted. Thanks!